# Unable to connect to Spotify - phantom ad blocker?

Tags: custom-roms, 7.0-nougat, connection-issues, spotify

I'm having issues with the Spotify app. Trying to search gives error messages shown in this [Spotify forum](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Android/Sorry-something-went-wrong/td-p/4439507). The solution suggested in that thread is to whitelist spclient.wg.spotify.com on my adblocker. I tried connecting to spclient.wg.spotify.com in Firefox and got an `Unable to connect` error.

I don't have an adblocker app or extension installed. I tested it out on [simple-adblock](http://simple-adblock.com/faq/testing-your-adblocker/) and found that my adblocker failed to block ads, but on [fivefilters](https://blockads.fivefilters.org/?pihole), it worked. So I'm not sure what to make of that.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android v7.0. I installed the ROM myself to get rid of the bloatware that came with the phone by following the instructions [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/samsung-galaxy-s7-roms-kernels-recoveries--other-development-snapdragon/rom-verizon-tmo-hybrid-method-t3571983). My best guess is that that ROM is tweaked to have a native adblocker. I think that might have been the case, but I can't remember, having it installed a good few months ago.

How can I whitelist spclient.wg.spotify.com when I don't know how to access whatever ad blocker is on my phone, if there is one? Can anyone offer an alternative explanation?

Comment: Check your `hosts` file. Most ad blocker use it to re-route ad domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert got it. My hosts file is full of URLs rerouted to 127.0.0.1. Thanks!